# SSRS using chart to display data

Tags: reporting-services, charts, reportingservices-2005

Has anyone here used chart object in SSRS to display data graphically?
I would like to know what are "Drop data fields here", "Drop serues fields here" & "Drop category fields here" ?

What are data fields, series fields and category fields?

FWC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you imagine XY trend then Data Fields will be Y coordinates, Category Fields will be X coordinates and Series Fields will be values for grouping data in different lines.

Talking about chart, usually Data Fields are for values, Category Fields are for dates and Series Fields may be products or departments. Category and Series Fields may be switched but usually fields with a lesser amount of descent values are chosen for Series Fields.

See [Steve Joubert: Beginning SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services Part 3: The Chart Control](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=297)